# TypeError: Cannot read property 'q1' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've designed my mongoose schema with a make up of objects inside it like so. Here is User.js:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
   name:String,
   surname:String,
   questions: {
    q1:{statement:String, spoof:Boolean},
    q2:{statement:String, spoof:Boolean},
    q3:{statement:String, spoof:Boolean}
 },
 color:{
   red:Number,
   green:Number,
   blue:Number
 }
});

var User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
module.exports = User;`
```

So I want three questions and then three numbers which seems fine.
However when I require this schema and refer to User.questions it says it is undefined even though I have defined it in the schema?
Here is where I handle the POST data from a form and try to save it to the DB

```
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {

   User.firstname = req.body.firstname;
   User.surname = req.body.surname;
   User.questions.q1.statement = req.body.q1;
   User.questions.q1.spoof = strToBoolean(req.body.q1Spoof);
   User.questions.q2.statement = req.body.q2;
   User.questions.q2.spoof = strToBoolean(req.body.q2Spoof);
   User.questions.q3.statement = req.body.q3;
   User.questions.q3.spoof = strToBoolean(req.body.q3Spoof);
   User.color.red = 255;
   User.color.green = 255;
   User.color.blue = 255;
   User.save(err => console.log("Did not save to database: \n" + err));

});
```

The strToBoolean function turns a string to a boolean
This should be straightforward? But I haven't yet seen any answers that help me in my case. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `req.body.q1` should be `req.body.questions.q1`

Comment: It shouldn't be though req.body.q1 is a string value of which I want to set User.questions.q1.statement equal to

Comment: I assumed the data you recieved had the same format than the one you are saving it into. Can you show the content of `req`?

Comment: `{ firstname: 'Joe',
  surname: 'Bloggs',
  q1: 'I like running',
  q1Spoof: 'true',
  q2: 'I love to sleep',
  q2Spoof: 'true',
  q3: 'I like to walk',
  q3Spoof: 'false' }`

Comment: Sorry for that formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User` is a model. You need to instantiate a document based on this model and assign your variables to that:

```
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {

   let user = new User()
   user.firstname = req.body.firstname;
   user.surname = req.body.surname;
   user.questions.q1.statement = req.body.q1;
   user.questions.q1.spoof = strToBoolean(req.body.q1Spoof);
   user.questions.q2.statement = req.body.q2;
   user.questions.q2.spoof = strToBoolean(req.body.q2Spoof);
   user.questions.q3.statement = req.body.q3;
   user.questions.q3.spoof = strToBoolean(req.body.q3Spoof);
   user.color.red = 255;
   user.color.green = 255;
   user.color.blue = 255;
   user.save(err => console.log("Did not save to database: \n" + err));

});
```

I'm not sure how Mongoose handles nested object schemas when no defaults exist, so you may need to instantiate the questions object and each of `q1`, `q2` and `q3` before you can assign to them too:

```
   user.questions = {q1: {}, q2: {}, q3: {}};
   user.questions.q1.statement = req.body.q1;
```

You can also create your document by passing an object to the constructor:

```
   let user = new User({
     firstname: req.body.firstname,
     surname: req.body.surname,
     questions: {
      q1: {
        statement: req.body.q1,
        spoof: strToBoolean(req.body.q1Spoof)
      },
      q2: {
        statement: req.body.q2,
        spoof: strToBoolean(req.body.q2Spoof)
      },
      q3: {
        statement: req.body.q3,
        spoof: strToBoolean(req.body.q3Spoof)
      }
    }
    color: {
      red: 255,
      green: 255,
      blue: 255
    }
   })
   user.save(err => console.log("Did not save to database: \n" + err));
```